# Battery consumption comparison of Unity, Gnome, Gnome Classic XFCE and LXDE

Tags: battery

I would like to know what is the rank of the current LTS version in term of probable consumption of battery power -ie: for a same usage.
Is the following rank probably correct, where top of the rank means "uses the highest level of battery power", and where bottom of the rank means "needs the less level of battery power":

Concerning Ubuntu 14.04

1. Ubuntu Unity
2. Ubuntu Gnome
3. Ubuntu Gnome Classic
4. Xubuntu
5. Lubuntu

That will usefull for people who would like to optimize their instant battery duration, like travellers using laptop for example.

Comment: Why? To me all you need to do is install TLP as explained here: http://askubuntu.com/a/285681/15811 and you will get the best outcome. The choice of OS should be based on hardware specs and there are so many notebooks (even the same model does not imply the same hardware). My notebook with 14.04 (so Unity) lasts 4 hours using smplayer and I did not tweak it besides installing TLP.

Comment: Thanks Rinzwind. The question is not "why ?", or "how to optimize ?", but the question is: "what is the rank ?".

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is in the right order (maybe change unity and gnome around?).

Answer (score 1):

To consume the minimum battery charge you have to load at minimum your pc, so use the minimum resources and this include ram.

The order that you did is correct, is difficult to make a rank because it varies. But if you want realy load at minimum your ram you can choose [Enlightenment](http://www.enlightenment.org/p.php?p=about/e17&l=en).